# Deleting Body in Box2d - C++

Tags: c++, box2d, sfml

I've tried looking for a solution for this issue everywhere to no avail. I've also tried many different approaches to try and resolve this problem myself but, nothing worked.

Everytime I try to delete a body from the world, I get a read access violation at the IsLocked method in Box2d.

I have tried creating a vector list and then deleting all of the bodies from the world that are in that list. Before deleting I make sure to check that I'm not stepping the world and that there are no duplicates in my list and that the world isn't locked.

I add them to the list like so:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < m_PlankObjects.size(); i++)
{
    m_Game->m_DestroyObjectList.push_back(m_PlankObjects[i].GetBody());
}
```

This is the GetBody() method:

```
b2Body * GameObject::GetBody()
{
    return m_Body;
}
```

m_Body is defined like so:

```
b2Body* m_Body;
```

And destroy like so:

```
if (m_UpdateWorld)
{
    World.Step(1 / 60.f, 8, 3);
}
else
{
    if (!World.IsLocked())
    {
        if (m_DestroyObjectList.size() != 0)
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < m_DestroyObjectList.size(); i++)
            {
                World.DestroyBody(m_DestroyObjectList[i]);
                m_DestroyObjectList.erase(m_DestroyObjectList.begin() + i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what's happening here and my box2d knowledge is a bit rusty. I had an issue once because destroying a b2Body can cause the EndContact callback to be called (in the next simulation step). If you don't expect that, you could read a pointer in that callback that has already been deleted.

Comment: @zett42 I've not implemented any code for any contact listeners though. Does this mean I have to implement and handle it?

Comment: I don't think so. If you don't already use it, it shouldn't have an impact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a night's sleep I went back to the issue and debugged it. I found out that I was not clearing the m_PlankObjects array and therefore in the next game loop update it was being accessed again, but since there were no bodies to access, Box2d was throwing an exception.

Comment: Good that you could find it out by yourself. "Sleep a night over it" should be a valid answer on SO! ;-)